# can't login through ssh after ubuntu 14.04 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, ssh, login

Ubuntu workstation (without monitor) was upgraded successfully to 14.04 and rebooted.

But I can't log in since then through ssh.

Is there any fix?

Upgraded using

```
do-release-upgrade
```

On successful upgrade message rebooted

```
reboot
```

Output from ssh -v

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to XX.XXX.XXX.XX [XX.XX.XXX.XX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address XX.XXX.XXX.XX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XXX.XX port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Can you ping the machine by IP address?

Comment: Run `ssh` in verbose mode (`-v`) and [edit] your question to include both the the command and the output.

Comment: Most probably is a case of http://serverfault.com/questions/416779/smoothest-workflow-to-handle-ssh-host-verification-errors --- but yes, as @DavidFoerster said, more data is needed.

Comment: Also, which host was upgraded? Server or client?

Comment: The workstation itself was upgraded, to which I cannot connect anymore.